# css: howto underline a block, but not the parts where it has text

Tags: html, css, underline

I want to to get the following result:

> __*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*____Title of page

So let's say the html markup is `<h1>Title of page</h1>` and h1 is set to `width:100%`and `text-align:right`, I want it only be underlined on the left side of the title.

Any clue how to accomplish that? I have tried to wrap the title in a `<div>`, give that a background of white and shift it a bit down, so it overlaps the bottom of the h1-box, however, I'm not sue whether this works 100% cross-browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

alternative solution:

```
<div style="width:100%;float:left;border-bottom:1px solid">
 <h1 style="float:right;background-color:white;padding:1px;position:relative;top:1px">Hola</h1>
</div>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VMCax/1/

Comment: Wow, that is quick. many thanks all! and special thanks to MCSI :)

Comment: about the :before pseudo-element solutions: they are not very flexible in terms of if you can't predict how long the actual title will be right?

Comment: That's right Mixhael, it also brings up the question with this solution if you have a title that breaks to multiple lines, this will only create the underline affect for the last line (unless you write multiple heading tags to consider the breaks)

Comment: Please don't post *only* a link to jsfiddle, post the content here as well.

Comment: Although your solutions works very well, I encountered an odd problem. It might be due to conflicts with other CSS declarations. But if you look to my website (which is in progress): http://guerrillabyt.es/ you will see that the line slides a pixel up for each menu-item. On the first menu-item it's perfectly aligned, but on the fourth (it seems that) there is 3 pixels difference. Any clue?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this as long as the line is not crucial to display content as it has support on IE8+.

```
h1:before{content:"________________"}​
```

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8hcS/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like what you are trying to do would be better achieved with a wrapper container and a float inside. Make the inner div (or floated h1) have a white background. Make the outer div have a repeated (repeat-y) background that is the same spacing as the line-height of the text div.

Make sure the wrapper div respects the floated div (either overflow:hidden or with a clear div at the end of the float.

This will give you the effect you are looking for and should work with multi-line titles as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with CSS generated content, with non-breaking spaces and underline : http://jsfiddle.net/JMVUa/1/

```
h1:before{
    content:"\a0\a0\a0\a0\a0\a0\a0\a0\a0\a0\a0\a0\a0";
    text-decoration: underline;
}​
```

Comment: Is there any difference between your approach and mine?

Comment: Yes, underscore characters may not look like "real" underlining. But anyway, this solution is not what Mixhael wanted.